# Make a sync method from async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Suppose I had an async method like

```
public async Task<bool> GetBoolAsync() 
{
    // Do some stuff
    return await GetMyBoolFromSomeFunction(somestuff);
}
```

and I wanted a synchronous version, this compiles just fine, but is it the correct way?

```
public bool GetBool() 
{
    return GetBoolAsync().Result;
}
```

or if there were no return value,

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync() 
{
    // Do some stuff
    await DoSomethingFromSomeFunction(somestuff);
}

public void DoSomething() 
{
    DoSomethingAsync().Wait();
}
```

Comment: The correct way is to go async all the way. Sometimes you have to fake it for a while so you can use `Task.FromResult(...)` to keep the method "asynchronous". Otherwise `ConfigureAwait` and `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` might work. It depends.

Comment: The correct way is to make all your calling methods async as this sort of thing can lead to blocking issues.